# Cs Data structures home work question - min heap

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, heap

the question:
the number of comparisons between **sorted array (with n elements)** and  minimum heap is  **n-1**

what I know :
I know that sorted array is min-heap, but what about the comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

If the array is **sorted from small -> big numbers** then there is no need for comparisons, therefore the answer is not correct.